# Jetpack compose: No method shouldWaitForActivitiesToComplete()

Tags: android, android-testing, android-instrumentation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm at the state where I want to write *androidTests* for the app.

Reading the docs of [**Testing Compose**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing#setup), I created a file and write a simple test to examine the progress:

---

ExamineTest.kt:

```kotlin
class ExamineTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()


    @Test
    fun atLaunchDefaultTextExists() {
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            Text(text = "text")
        }
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithText("text").assertIsDisplayed()
    }
}
```

Also I added the debug `AndroidManifest` at the `app/src/debug/` to enable ComposeActivity as suggested in docs.

However, by running the test nothing will happen and the test will not start executing.

Here's the state that test gets stock at (App is built and deployed. But not started to run tests. Normal execution of app works correctly):

[image: show case where test gets stuck]

Am I missing a part on the setup ? What is the reason that tests are not running?

---

**compose**: 1.0.0-alpha05
**AS**: 4.2-canary 14

#### Update

After debugging the test and check it's logs, I see this error:

```
No method shouldWaitForActivitiesToComplete() in 
androidx/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure `test:monitor` and `test:core` are up to date.

Checking out this issue on Android-test github, I realized the issue might be because of `test:monitor` being older than needed. So I did these steps:

1. Check Gradle task `app:dependencies` to see the version of `test:monitor` library
2. If it's indeed old (which was `1.2.0` and not the latest `1.3.0`), find the library that downgrades it.

   in my case `fragment-testing` was downgrading it to `1.2`, so I removed it.

After making sure `test:monitor` and `test:core` are up to date, I could finally run the test